# Conditional expected number of runs in a sequence of coin flips

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78237/expected-number-of-runs-in-a-sequence-of-coin-flips) question talks about expected number of runs in a series of coin flips. I have a related problem where i need to calculate the CONDITIONAL expectation of runs in a series of $n$ flips, given $n_1$ of them are heads, and $n_2$ are tails such that $n_1 + n_2 = n$. I represent this conditional expectation by $E(n_1, n_2)$

Using similar logic as above question, I tried this:

Given $n_1$, $n_2$ and $E(n_1, n_2)$, $E(n_1 + 1, n_2)$ should increment by $1$ if last toss was tails (prob${}=\frac{n_2}{n_1 + n_2}$

$$E(n_1 + 1,  n_2) = E(n_1, n_2) + \frac {n_2}{n_1+n_2} $$

Similarly

$$E(n_1,  n_2 + 1) = E(n_1, n_2) + \frac {n_1}{n_1+n_2}  $$

Starting with $E(n_1, 0) = E(0, n_2) = 1$, I get

$$E(n_1, n_2) = 1 + \sum_k (\frac{n_1}{n_1+k} )   = 1 + \sum_k (\frac{n_2}{n_2+k} ) $$

But this doesn't look right. Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: The answer will not depend on the value of $p.$ That information is superseded by the information about how many heads and how many tails you got.

Comment: Agreed, I am not using p anywhere. I also removed it from the description now.

Comment: Note that instead of writing $\displaystyle \sum_k ( \frac{n_1}{n_1+k} ) $ you can write $\displaystyle \sum_k \left( \frac{n_1}{n_1+k} \right).$ (But in this instance the parentheses aren't really needed.)

Answer (score 1):

The important part here is to understand that given $n_1,n_2$, the probability that two consecutive tosses are different is no longer depends on $p$, but rather equals to $2\tfrac{n_1 n_2}{n(n-1)}$.
The reason is that the number of $H$ and $T$ is fixed so it is only a question of how they are arranged in a row. The probability of $H$ on a particular throw is $\tfrac{n_1}{n}$ and the probability of tails on the next throw is $\tfrac{n_2}{n-1}$.

The rest of the solution should be identical to the linked question, so the answer should be
$$1+2\tfrac{n_1 n_2}{n_1+n_2}$$

Comment: So it shouldn't depend on $p$.

Comment: It shouldn't be there to begin with. Try the simple case $E(1,0)=1$ but $E(1,1)=2$. The recursion formula is incorrect, as it should take into account that the number of everything is known.

Comment: Agreed, i modified the recursion above. In addition, probability of heads = n1/n is probably true only for first place, but not afterwards?

Comment: It is true for each place individually (symmetry. No reason for more heads in throw #5 over #1)