# Testing the generation of a sequence of zeros and ones

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution, hypothesis-testing

I am given a sequence of $40$ ones and zeros, and I have to test whether the sequence is random (in the problem this is said to be equivalent to testing the null hypothesis that all ${40 \choose n_1}$ possible sequences are equally probable, $n_1$ being the number of ones). To do so, I have to use the number of times that 1 became 0 and vice versa and then apply normal approximation.

What I did so far is define $Z:=1_{X_j \neq X_{j+1}}$ and then the number of 0-1 and 1-0 changes is $I:= \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}Z_j$ (which is binomial); I then calculated its expectation (following this similar [Stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/78242/543735)). From here on, I am stuck. What does it mean to use $I$ to show that "${40 \choose n_1}$ sequences are all equally probable"? How do I exactly use $I$ and normal approximation to test randomness?

Comment: I don't understand.  How could looking at one single sequence possibly tell you that all possibilities were equally likely?

Comment: @lulu https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_runs_test

Comment: Your computation computes the number of runs, and your linked "runs test" explains how to test for independence in the sequence .

Comment: I don't understand.  Did you possibly mean to ask "test whether the null hypothesis 'this sequence was decided by  independent tosses of a fair (or possible unfair) coin' can be rejected"?  That's a radically different question.

Comment: @lulu yes, sorry for formulating the question in the wrong way

Comment: Ok, so, assuming the null hypothesis, you have the theoretical distribution of the number of runs.  And you have the actual number of runs.  How likely was that observation?  How many standard deviations off the mean was it?  As usual, you need to decide (in advance) how quick you'll be to reject the null hypothesis.  What confidence you had in mind, that is.

Comment: The probability of obtaining the following specific sequences are of course the same:   $000\ldots 0$, $111\ldots 1$, $01010\ldots$, $011010\ldots 1$.  Each appears with probability $P = (1/2)^{40}$.  I think you need to refine your question.